Issues Building App Bundle Targeting API Level 34
I want to get API level 34 .abb file for Android platform in unity but I get this error message:

Here are the external packages I am using:


I am able to get API level 33 build without any problem but I have to delete /Library/Bee file before the build otherwise I won't even be able to get API level 33 build file. I am also deleting /Library/Bee for API level 34 but that doesn't seem to work
This is the Project Settings => Player => Other Settings => Configuration

How can I solve this issue ?
Edit
Here are the console details:

Unity version: 2021.3.33f1

"See the Console for details"

Android SDK 34 is supported on 2021.3.41f1+ versions of Unity
Android SDK to Unity versions availability#
